# wordpress: how do I align background image left?

Tags: wordpress, alignment, background-image

I am using Wordpress with a pretty standard template that sets a landing page background image via (linebreaks for easier readability here)

```
[full_width_section textcolor="#3333333"
image="https://MYSITE/wp-content/uploads/FILE"
bgpos="cover" bgatt="fixed"]
```

The image is bigger than the screen resolution and thus gets cropped on the right side to fit the screen. I'd rather keep the right edge of the image and crop the left. How do I do this?

Comment: Short codes are designed either with the theme or a plug in. And varies greatly by theme. You might check the developer of the theme to see if they have documentation on what attributes are available.  I’m leaning towards the bgpos one. Because it’s currently set to cover, the image will fill the available space, if you adjust your window wider and shorter you’ll probably see the right side. I’d also try changing it to: bgpos=“cover right” but not sure how the theme builds the css so may not work.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark pointed out in the comment; each short codes are designed for specific theme or plugin; they work differently for each theme. You can always checkout the documentation for it and find available options.

But if you don't want to go into all those trouble. You can just add a custom css to the class in which the background image is loading and change the alignment; for ex.

```
.bg_cover {
      background-position: left top;
      //you can use various other options as per your requirement such as left center, left bottom, etc..
}
```

Hope I help